# Ignoring specific rows with VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Excel like such, where the number of rows will vary each day:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Show |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Show |
| Cell 5 | Cell 6 | Ignore |

I am using vba to convert the range to a html table, and then email it.
I have a helper column (Column C), and I want to use a formula there to filter out certain rows.
However, that filter is not excluding hidden cells from being displayed in the html table.

I currently use this

`Dim LastRow As Long LastRow = rInput.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row`

to find the last row of my table. This works great in projects where you want all of the table included.
I tried to change it to `Find("Ignore",` which gets me `Object variable or With block variable not set`

I tried including 'SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)' in my

`ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(Sheet2.Range("$A:$J").Rows("5:" & LastRow), 5)`

and using a filter to hide the 'Ignore' cells. But that did not stop them showing in the emailed html table.

Comment: Youl would need to modify your `ConvertRangeToHTMLTable` routine and have it ignore the rows that are hidden, as they are still part of the `Range`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up adjusting the table (and thus the range I cared about) to start at row 1 rather than row 5, and using

`strBody = dsaEmailHeader & ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(Sheet2.Range("$A:$H").Rows("1:" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))`

worked, where it didn't previously.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some sort of loop which goes over the rows right? It will not automatically skip the hidden rows just because they are filtered out, you need to specifically tell it to skip them. You can do something like:

```
For Each r In myRange.Rows
    If Not r.EntireRow.Hidden Then
        doSomething
    End If
Next r
```